# Heavy Light Decomposition

Tags: algorithm, tree

I came across an algorithm known as **Heavy Light Decomposition**. I read about the algorithm from [here](http://blog.anudeep2011.com/heavy-light-decomposition/). The post was clear an I understood the algorithm and its working but I am having problem in implementing it. I can break the tree into segments using a simple DFS, but after that I can't figure out how to perform update and query operations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code or pseudo code you have so far? Do require the implementation in a specific language like Python or is pseudo code sufficient?

Comment: I would prefer psuedo code, its easy to understand

Comment: After breaking the tree into segments, you can build a segment tree to implement query and update operations in logarithmic time. You can see implementation here (for problem QTREE on spoj) https://github.com/anudeep2011/programming/blob/master/qtree.cpp